# Unbranded YouTube Player After Depreciations

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, plyr.js

YouTube recently changed the `rel` and `showinfo` parameters when embedding video from YouTube, which means that custom players like Plyr will still show the YouTube logo and related videos for the first few seconds when played, and when paused. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: The depreciation makes using their platform for custom work nearly impossible. I guess self hosted MP4s are the best way to go now.